# Shift register that can source +-15V?

Tags: transistors, high-voltage, pins, shift-register, ttl

I need to source +15V or -15V resp. on several pins (20+) using a few TTL level pins (SPI, I2C, serial) from my microcontroller. Only one of the pins will source +15V at a time, the rest are -15V.

I can only find shift registers that can sink high current, for example the TPIC6B595, not source it. The only components I've found are analog arrays with serial interfaces, but that's overkill and becomes very expensive.

Maybe I don't understand the spec of the TPIC6B595 correct, but I think I want the same component but I want them to sink current (from a Vdd pin) instead of draining to GND as the DRAIN pins do now.

I'm looking for a component that can be connected like U1 below and the Pin1-Pin8 can be toggled to either +15V or -15V. The actual serial interface is not important, just any serial interface. Maybe two components are needed, one for +15V and one for -15V.

[image: Schematics v2]

Comment: Current or voltage?

Comment: I'll have a Voltage source of (dual) +-15V and GND behind the IC, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: **1.** What do you mean by "behind the IC", which IC are you talking about and, also, how much current do you need to source/sink? **2.** How about a schematic?

Comment: yay for schematics that explain what you want to do!

Comment: ![Schematics](http://imgur.com/a/6KmiS)

Comment: You use the word "current", but only define the _voltage_. What **current** do you want to source or sink?

Comment: The TPIC6B595 doesn't source anything.  Its outputs are FETs that pull the output to ground.  The voltage on the output can be up to 50V.

Comment: Not that much current, 30-100mA.

Comment: you need 3 to 5 V logic converter, common ground and single Vcc to loads not the chip. This is a 5V logic chip with open drain to pullup load eg 24V

Comment: I don't want to use the TPIC6B595, but I want something similar that can source current. Or even better, something with + and - 15V.

Comment: You're going to have to do this with (at least) two components: a shift register, and some kind of power driver/buffer/level shifter. Some of the RS232 shifters might be suitable. Note that 100ma per pin times 8 pins is actually quite a lot and will require considering heat.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into the RS232 components. I think the -15V current will be really low and that the one pin of +15V can be limited into the proper range.

Comment: If you said 10mA, you could have used two MC1488/SN55188/SN75188 as a +-15V push/pull line driver. Maybe there's a 30mA variant out there somewhere. 100mA, no chance.

Comment: It'll only be a short spike, maybe it can be limited to 10mA. I'll try the MC1488 together with shift registers. Thanks

Comment: this is a poor defined requirement.  define target load device and characteristics and pulse properties and anything else relevant

Comment: I agree with you Tony. This is a test board to find out the end-requirements.

Answer (score 1):

As I see it you have three requirements:

1. You want to convert a 0V to 5V TTL signal to -15V to +15V - which you can supply;
2. You have a large number (>20) of outputs that you want to control with a minimum of TTL-level microcontroller pins;
3. You only need one output to be at +15V at once.

That last implies that you want a 5-to-32 demultiplexor, not a shift register - although a shift register would need only 3 pins, at the sacrifice of speed to change the outputs while the new "ON" pin was shifted into place:

a. Clock;
b. Shift-in data;
c. Latch output.

Regardless of the format though, you have a 0/5V signal that you want converted to -15/+15V. That basically precludes a lot of semiconductor solutions such as FETs and transistors, since their outputs are based on their inputs (including triggers); and you want more than that.

You mention serial converters: there are two versions of these. One that uses an input to switch the +/- supply (à la the 1488, but that's limited to 10mA max output); or a charge-pump device such as the MAX232 which makes its own +/- voltage from the 0/5V supply. The former is not strong enough; the latter is unnecessary (you have the voltages, you don't need to create them) and expensive - and probably also not strong enough.

So you could control a bank of relays, either solid state or mechanical, or a bank of high-current op-amps. For the op-amp solution, something like TI's LM7332 dual op-amp may work:

- It can be supplied with +/- 15V;
- It offers 100 mA on its outputs;
- You can supply the desired 0-5V signal on the non-inverting input;
- Put a reference 2.5V from a voltage divider on the inverting input.

If the non-inverting input is below 2.5V, the op-amp will drop to the negative voltage. Above 2.5V, the op-amp will jump to the positive voltage.